# Aligning Multi-line text and images within a table header cell

Tags: css

quick question I'm struggling with, hopefully I've just got a brain-blockage and I'm missing something simple.

We've got a bunch of table headers, some of which have sort up/down arrows in them.  We want the text to be left-aligned and the images to be right-aligned within the table header cell.  I've got the 2 arrow images within a span container (but this can be a div) with nowrap applied to it to ensure they are always displayed side-by-side (this is also a requirement).  The complexity is some of our table-header text needs to be split over 2 lines - this is currently done with a br in the text.  When I use float:right to right align the images, they vertically align with the top of the multi-line text, rather than with the middle of the cell.  What am I doing wrong (maybe it's getting a little late) or do I need to completely rethink my strategy?

Thx MH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This pretty much seems like it can't be done - we can get close, but each solution to get it all working together breaks something else.  Thanks for the suggestions

Answer (score 1):

Use divs with float:left for the header text and float:right for the images. The vertical-align: top the header. Sorry about the nasty coloring. I'm not a designer.

You can fiddle with it at [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j5zCK/35/).

Test table:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            <div class="title">a header with a </br>br thing </div>
            <div class="updown">up down</div></th>
        <th>
            <div class="title">a header</div>
            <div class="updown">up down</div>
        </th>
        <th>
            <div class="title">more headers</div>
            <div class="updown">up down</div>
        </th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Style:

```
th, td { border: 1px solid green; }
th { width: 200px; vertical-align: top; }

.title { float: left; border: solid 1px purple; overflow: hide; }
.updown { border: solid 1px red; float: right; }
```

Comment: Thanks, that's almost there (and pretty much what I had) but it doesn't work with the vertical-align: middle and I think they're going to be picky about the arrows being vertically centered - any ideas on that?

Comment: quick answer, you can always go for tables inside the header. getting the vertical-align: middle in was a harder nut to crack. i'll be looking into it some more.

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking of having to resort to something like that, but if you can come up with anything better I'd be appreciated.  I'll keep looking and poking too - bloody pain in the arse requirement.... but it doesn't look very good top-aligned, unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

Try vertical-align: middle on the image.

Comment: That was the first thing I tried but it doesn't seem to work - have you got this working in an example?

Comment: If the above answer doesn't help you, can you post your code?